# Heroku - CSV Files and TXT Logfiles

Tags: python, heroku

I want to deploy a python bot to heroku.
The bot writes all logging data to txt files and also exports a CSV file to the filesystem where data is stored that is important for the next run of the bot and as well makes it possible to track past performance of the bot.
As I know that it is not possible to store any files at a heroku dyno persistent the question is - how/where to store the data?

A database for the data in the csv file is not suitable for me because I have to edit the file sometimes between two runs and to do this via a database would be to much effort for me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the file(s) on an external storage like S3, DropBox, GitHub, etc..
Check [Files on Heroku](https://medium.com/geekculture/files-on-heroku-cd09509ed285) to see options and examples.

You can decide to read/write the files directly from the storage (i.e. no local copy), or also keep the files locally making sure they are saved at some point (every 10 min, before every restart).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Maybe you can also tell me whether it is possible that the dyno restarts while my script is running? I cannot imagine that it works that way

Comment: It is possible, Heroky Dyno restarts once a day (randomly). If you restart manually (`heroku ps:restart`) then you reset the 24hr window.